# Why is my css file for my ul class links keep on getting overwritten by user agent stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

Can somebody help me please, as this is causing me sleepless nights. I've programmed a website with a navigation bar. The CSS code works fine when it is within the HTML code but when it is in a separate file the CSS code seems to only work on the li tags but not for the ul tags. Please see below for HTML & then the CSS.

```css
ul.OPEN_menu {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #c00;
  border: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  list-style: none;
  font: bold 20px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: initial;
}

ul.closedMENU {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #c00;
  border: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  list-style: none;
  font: bold 20px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul.closedsubmenu li {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 6.9em;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -45px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul.OPEN_submenu li {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 6.9em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 13px;
  visibility: visible;
  font: bold 24px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul.menu,
ul.menu ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu a {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li ul li a {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li.submenu:hover {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li.submenu:hover ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li.submenu:hover ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li.submenu:hover ul li:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="OPEN_menu OPEN_submenu" id="box1">
  <div id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN">Menu</div>
  
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Game_Art_Work.html">Game Art Work</a></li>
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Games.html">Games</a></li>
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Games_D.html">Game D</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The div should not be inside the ul. Also can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: BTW. `ul` cannot have `div` as direct children. Your HTML is invalid

Comment: AND, IDs must be unique and only used ONCE per page.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input